# How should I convert .sblive to .iso in xubuntu-20.04 Kernel 5.11.0-46

Tags: xubuntu, iso

The previous question for converting .sblive to .iso asked by Edwards Torwalds was answered by kyodake back in 2015. I have created .sblive file for my system a few days ago. It appears in the list of files "created live images". Even if I mark the file in that list, the button "Convert to ISO" remains grayed out. The action can't be initiated. The size of my .sblive file is 2,7GB. What should I do in such a case? Is there any work-around for this? Any suggestions will be well appreciated.

Comment: A Xubuntu 20.04 LTS system should be using the 5.4 kernel (*if using GA kernel stack*) or 5.15 (*if using the HWE kernel stack*) so I'd check your details, as it shows incorrect details, an un-updated system, or something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My Xubuntu 20.04 LTS is really running on 5.11.0-46 kernel. Synaptic doesn't show any kernel update, which I could use. Shall be looking into this again. I will definitely give it a try and report back.

Comment: The 5.11 kernel was from Ubuntu 21.04 which was the kernel of 20.04.3, however a updated Ubuntu 20.04 or *focal* system currently will be using the kernels stack from 20.04.5 even though it'll still be reporting itself as 20.04.4 as changes are currently rolling out in the 20.04.5, and the version (.4 to .5) is the last change. Ubuntu 21.04 is EOL thus why 5.11 isn't, likewise 21.10 is EOL why 5.13 kernel was replaced by 5.15 from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I'd start with `sudo apt update` as your system is *unpatched* & using a very old kernel shows problems or your system isn't a real Xubuntu one.

Comment: Your clarification is very helpful. What I don't understand is this: The installation was done  with cdimage of xubuntu-20.04.1 and it has been updated at regular intervals since then. I use it for creating  .sblive only, without any data collection whatsoever except for the configuration files of users. Is there any reason why such an installation gets "unpatched"? I use synaptic to do the updates. It would be good to know to prevent this from happening again! I am hesitant to do the suggested update, since systemback may stop functioning after 20.04 (as mentioned by its creator kyodake).

Comment: If you used the Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS ISO for installation, then your default kernel stack was the GA kernel, ie. 5.4 with no HWE stack.  My guess, and I can only guess, was someone on that machine manually installed the 5.11 kernel without HWE stack, thus the lack of updates for it, as you'd only get updates for the GA kernel stack that was correctly installed via installation.  Check your *apt* log (`/var/log/apt/history.log` etc) and it's maybe downloaded & installed as a single *self-maintained* kernel and not via HWE stack thus no updates for it due to non-HWE stack installs; my guess.

Comment: Just did a new and fresh install beginning with the current 20.04.4 xubuntu cdimage. Completed the configurations as required by my fellow users and created a new .sblive image. Guess, with this, there can't be any reason why systemback would stop me from converting .sblive to iso. Sorry, but that Button still remains grayed out. Can't create iso from .sblive! What could be done? Any suggestions would be appreciated.